# "Encoded" login names in SharePoint Client Object Model

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-api, sharepoint-clientobject

I'm writing a small .NET proof-of-concept console app that performs a series of actions on a SharePoint document library. I noticed that the following methods expect an "encoded" login name - that is, login name including provider information, e.g. `i:0#.w|DOMAIN\user`.

```
context.Web.EnsureUser(encodedLoginName);
context.Web.SiteUsers.GetByLoginName(encodedLoginName);
```

How do I reliably convert a user name such as `DOMAIN\user` to this encoded format in the **SharePoint Client Object Model**?

I've read a [couple](http://zimmergren.net/technical/tip-getting-the-normal-domain-username-from-the-claims-username-in-sharepoint-2013) of [blog posts](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/programmatically-converting-login-name-claim/) that address this issue with the `SPClaimProviderManager`, which is not available in the client API.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am able to get the encoded login name using the [ResolvePrincipal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.utilities.utility.resolveprincipal.aspx) utility method:

```
using SP = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
//...

// resolve user principal using regular login name or e-mail:
var userPrincipal = SP.Utilities.Utility.ResolvePrincipal(
  context, 
  context.Web, 
  "DOMAIN\\user", // normal login name
  SP.Utilities.PrincipalType.User,
  SP.Utilities.PrincipalSource.All,
  context.Web.SiteUsers,
  false);

context.ExecuteQuery();

// ensure that the user principal was resolved:
if (userPrincipal.Value == null)
  throw new Exception("The specified user principal could not be resolved");

// get a User instance based on the encoded login name from userPrincipal
var user = context.Web.SiteUsers.GetByLoginName(userPrincipal.LoginName);
context.Load(user);

context.ExecuteQuery();
```

This seems to work as intended. However, if there is a better way or caveats that I should be aware of, please let me know.

Comment: This worked for me only when I used email address instead of login name (domain\alias) in 3rd argument and set the last argument to true instead of false in the method ResolvePrincipal().

Comment: My `ClientContext` doesn't have `context.Web.SiteUsers`?. Will this method allow you to decode the claim token to DOMAIN\USER?